# Does anyone use Ceiling and *not* immediately cast it to an integer?

Tags: math, language-agnostic

I think every single time I've used `Math.Ceiling` or its language variant, I've *always* had to cast it to an integer. I mean... that's the whole point, isn't it? To get a whole number. So why doesn't it just return an `int`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For one, REALs/FLOATs usually have a much greater range. The result might not fit into an INTEGER.

Comment: This is exactly what the PHP documentation says for it's function: http://php.net/ceil

Comment: @Darryl Hein - Haha, interesting. Btw, nice docs - those.

Comment: One should also note that just as decimals sometimes can't be represented exactly with float, the same goes for really large integers.

Comment: @gablin - Good point!

Answer (score 2):

Smalltalk's does.

```
100000000000000000000.5 ceiling => 100000000000000000000
```

100000000000000000000 is a LargePositiveInteger, meaning an integer that uses more than 32 bits in its representation.

As Michael points out, the above answer is wrong. I didn't notice that while the answer was an integer the answer was wrong because the float loses precision. So instead here's another, CORRECT, version, which works because we don't use floats:

```
(100000000000000000000 + (1 / 2)) ceiling => 100000000000000000001
```

Comment: Wait... why wasn't that rounded up then?

Comment: @Ralph: Because the number has more digits than a floating point number can represent, so you lose some precision.

Comment: So.... `100000000000000000000.5` isn't exactly represented, no matter what you do with it?

Comment: @Ralph: Yes. 64-bit floating point can only represent all integers exactly up to 2^53, which gives about 16 digits of precision. If you need more than that, you will have to use a decimal type or an arbitrary precision library. Some C and C++ compilers/architectures also support 80-bit "long doubles" with around 19 digits.

Comment: Well, my point was that your answer is misleading. Even with the amendment... 1/2 == 0, doesn't it (at least in C++ it is)? You don't have any floats in there, so ceiling isn't really doing anything at all.

Comment: Your question's deliberately language-agnostic, and doesn't mention floats anywhere. So no, I don't think it's misleading: you CAN represent numbers exactly... if you don't use floats. And you could, for instance, use a library for arbitrary precision maths, which would give you mathematically correct answers for a whole host more numbers.